# How to manipulate LIst<Object>

Tags: android

I come to C# world and need to do a smal prototype in an Android App.
I am using Android Studio and a ThirdParty SDK for my project

I have trouble to access individual items of a collection . The collection is return as follow :

```
 public void onBeaconsUpdated(Region region, List<BeaconDevice> beaconDevices) {
            message = "Beacon updated";
          List<BeaconDevice> B=beaconDevices;
            var  Bd=beaconDevices;
            for(i=0;i<Bd.Size();i++)
            {

            }


        }
```

If try to access properties and methods of a given BeaconDevice indexed by the i pointer. By doing simply Bd[i] gives me an error saying that array is epxected.

How can I retrive each object in the collection and access theire properties ?

Regards
serge

Comment: have yoy tried `Bd.get(i)`

Comment: var  Bd=beaconDevices;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the other code, I think you are working on Java but this line bit confusing me,

`var  Bd=beaconDevices;`

As if you are on Java then you have to use your code like,

```
List<BeaconDevice> B=beaconDevices;

for(i=0;i<B.Size();i++)
{
 BeaconDevice beaconDevice = B.get(i);
}
```

Comment: @serge - glade to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to loop over a `List<BeaconDevice>` is like this:

```
for (BeaconDevice device : beaconDevices) {
    // do what needs to be done with device
}
```

See [The `for` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Note: The `var` keyword that you have in C# does not exist in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a foreach loop :

```
List<BeaconDevice> B=beaconDevices;
foreach(BeaconDevice bd in B)
{
    //do whatever you need to do
}
```